# Value cards not displaying in boxes on Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, bslib

I am creating a shiny app with this layout:

[image]

There are meant to be 4 cards on the top row, and then two plotly graphs underneath. I would like the cards to appear in boxes like this:

[image]

But why is it only showing the text? I am using the `bslib` library.

The code for the app below is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(bslib)
library(lorem)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test title"),
  sidebarPanel(
    width = 2,
    h2(""),
    dateRangeInput('dateRange_last_week',
                   label = 'For the time period:',
                   start = Sys.Date()-365, end = Sys.Date()),
    
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "picker_1",
      label = "Picker 1", 
      choices = NULL,
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, `live-search` = TRUE),
      multiple = TRUE),
    
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "picker_2",
      label = "Picker 2:", 
      choices = NULL,
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, `live-search` = TRUE),
      multiple = TRUE)),
  
  mainPanel(
    layout_column_wrap(
      heights_equal = "all", full_screen = TRUE, width = 1/4,
      card(card_header("A long, scrolling, description"),
           card_body(lorem::ipsum(paragraphs = 3, sentences = 5))),
      card(card_header("A long, scrolling, description"),
           card_body(lorem::ipsum(paragraphs = 3, sentences = 5))),
      card(card_header("A long, scrolling, description"),
           card_body(lorem::ipsum(paragraphs = 3, sentences = 5))),
      card(card_header("A long, scrolling, description"),
           card_body(lorem::ipsum(paragraphs = 3, sentences = 5)))
      ),
      
      fluidRow(
        column(6,
               plotlyOutput("test_plot_1")),
        column(6,
               plotlyOutput("test_plot_2")))
      
      
      
    )
  )
  
  
  # Define server logic required to draw a histogram
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    
    
    output$test_plot_1 <- renderPlotly({
      fig <- ggplot2::diamonds
      fig <- fig %>% count(cut, clarity)
      fig <- fig %>% plot_ly(x = ~cut, y = ~n, color = ~clarity)
      
      fig
    })
    
    
    output$test_plot_2 <- renderPlotly({
      x= c(1, 2, 3, 5.5, 10)
      y= c(10, 8, 6, 4, 2)
      width = c(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 3.5, 4)
      data <- data.frame(x, y, width)
      
      fig <- plot_ly(data)
      fig <- fig %>% add_bars(
        x= ~x,
        y= ~y,
        width = ~width
      )
      
      fig
    })
    
    
    
    
  }
  
  # Run the application 
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - ended up using fluidrow instead!